# Restrict pdf files to be download by user but able to be executed by aspx or asp

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I'm looking for a solution which restricts .pdf files to be downloaded by user but retrievable by aspx or asp, I've tried to add the following lines to the web.config file within system.web tag in the website root directory:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

But an internal server error occurs when I access the website. Does anyone know how to do this, I'm testing it on IIS 7 on windows 7.

***Update***
 i've successfuly configured:

```
<add name="NoPdfAllowed" verb="*" path="download/*.pdf" 
   type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
</handlers>
```

But I have a java applet plugin (a html/asp/aspx page) that can't open the pdf after I add the above lines in the web.config file. Is it possbile to enable the java applet able to load the pdf?

Comment: Do you have access to the IIS settings?

Comment: I don't have time to post a proper answer at the moment, but if you research wild-card mappings for IIS 7 you can force any file type to validate against .Net authentication and then you can use role security in the web.config to keep it all straight.

Comment: @joel, don't you think, that once authenticated, the PDF becomes accessible from within the session?

Comment: @hkinterview, what do you mean by 'retrievable by aspx or asp'? How will the PDF be consumed under the "allowed" scenario?

Answer (score 1):

How about just putting the pdf files outside the webdirectory?

Make a directory called C:\pdf-files\ and in this directory give the internet-user read rights. That way your asp and aspx files can use these files for whatever you need, but the users visiting the site cant access them?

IF you however use a function like adostream or similar the users might still be able to download the streamed content...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to disallow dowload of pdf files trough "direct" url, but allow them to be downloaded trough client anyway (java applet). This is kind of how to make rounded circle :)

I'm using this system on my hobby abandonware site for downloading zip files:

- Put pdfs out of the web site directory or disallow their extension as you already did
- When serving .aspx page with java applet, generate unique token (lets say new guid) that will contain unique identifier and pdf file name, store it in http cache (if you're using single box as server) or in db/scaleout (web farm), pass this token identifier to applet, this token should have just limited lifespan
- Create HttpHandler that will serve pdf files, this handler will (before serving the pdf) check by token id, if token is present and still valid, and will invalidate this token after serving pdf file
- You can also check for Referrer if it matches your domain, but I wouldn't recommend that, some browsers are not setting that one correctly

This way user can still download pdf files, but the download link will work only once, so they can't link your content (at least not so easily).